# create row level security in quicksight if the user belongs to a particular department

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, row-level-security, bi-tool

Lets say I have a dataset named Reports like this:

| department_name | account_id |
| --- | --- |
| Security | 1 |
| Marketing | 2 |

and I have users in my organization that are divided into departments, I want to be able to show only the departments in the quicksight dashboard in which the current user exists.

I have made a csv file like this:

| UserName | department_name |
| --- | --- |
| user_1 | Application |
| user_2 | Security |

and applied this csv with the Reports dataset and I am in Security department, I (user_2) opened the dashboard and saw only Security department_name rows and my co worker (user_1) is Application department and he saw only those rows.
but how can i do it when there are 1000+ employees, one way i thought of is making groups in quicksight and then naming those groups like Application_Group and then having a csv like this:

| GroupName | department_name |
| --- | --- |
| Application_Group | Application |

and I was seeing the right rows.
Does that mean I would have to make groups of all the departments in quicksight and add users in those groups and then create a csv of what group name is seeing what department?
Or is there any better way of doing it.